# Objectify query filter by list?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Is it possible to make an Objectify query with a list and get a list of all objects matching the list?  For example

```
List<String> vinNumberList;
Query<CarObject> q=ofy.query(CarObject.class).filter("vin",vinNumberList);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, its possible... add "in" , like this

```
ofy.query(CarObject.class).filter("vin in",vinNumberList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is what I needed.  How about a +1 on the question?

Comment: @Patrick i know this is a little old - is there a way to do a reverse of this - if you had a list in the object and needed to filter on whether or not the object contained the given value?

Comment: @seanchriste Yes, it is.  If you can ask the question then I can give you a proper answer, with example code.  Just put the link here so I can find it.

Comment: @Patrick here's the link, theres only 1 catch, it's using the ancestor(key) first then querying - anyway, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867401/objectify-query-filter-by-list-in-entity-contains-search-parameter

Comment: @Daniel does this also supported by Objectify V4 because I tested it with objectfy v4 and I got empty list returned. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292834/geospatial-radius-search-using-objectify I have also asked this question but didn't got any answer.

Comment: @AnkurJain , I haven't tested it on Objectify V4 , try to simplify your example and double check it with the answer I have provided...

Comment: How would you do this if your list was a list of `Long` ids that have a parent?

Comment: @MicroR , You better ask a new detailed question and explain waht entities you looking for

Comment: @Daniel Ok. I typed up a detailed question I hope is easy to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747921/objectify-query-filter-by-list-of-long-ids-that-have-a-parent